# How to navigate to external URL inside component in Angular 4?

Tags: angular, spotify

I am currently working with a node/express server as well as angular 4 and `ng build --watch --output-path` my project to make it easier to work with the endpoints I have created.

As of now, I am using the spotify web api to control my music by pressing a few html buttons. Initially I used the `HttpClient` module from Angular to make a `get` call as well as an observable. However from what I understand the `.subscribe()` doesn't handle non-JSON data well (I'm still really new to Angular and programming in general so I may be misunderstanding something). I have tested this out myself by doing the following code:

In my **music-control.component.html:**

```
<button (click)="pause($event)">Pause</button>
```

And in my **music-control.component.ts:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-music-control',
    templateUrl: './music-control.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./music-control.component.css']
})
export class MusicControlComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    ngOnInit() {
    }

    pause() {
        this.http.get('/pause').subscribe();
    }

}
```

FYI: My server-side code is working fine and have made the endpoint url `/pause`. I have tested this out `localhost:8000/pause` and the endpoint does indeed pause my Spotify song.

However when using the `subscribe()` method I am able to pause the song once but then after playing and then pausing it again, the endpoint returns an error (Error status: 500, 'Internal Server Error').

Alternatively I removed the `pause()` function I created in the `music-control.component.ts` file and instead used `<button><a href="/pause">Pause</a></button>` and it was working smoothly.

However, I am aiming to press a pause/play button and save track data (such as the time stamp of the song or the song track ID) and saving that to a postgreSQL table  I have created AND THEN pausing the song. So really I need to have a promise-like function in the `component.ts` file because the `href` solution will be not be viable.

Does the Angular RouteModule have a way to go to an external URL (essentially replicating what `href` does but in the `component.ts` file)? Or am I able to achieve this with the `subscribe()` solution?

Apologies if this question was lengthy...thanks!

Comment: I think you should go through the documentation for HttpClient Module in order to see how to handle non-JSON data, there is support for other types for example text and others.

Comment: Also, are you trying to post some data to your backend when the play/pause button is pressed?

Answer (score 0):

You can use router Module following methods:

For Relative URL

```
navigate(commands: any[], extras: NavigationExtras = { skipLocationChange: false }): Promise<boolean>
```

For absolute URL

```
navigateByUrl(url: string | UrlTree, extras: NavigationExtras = { skipLocationChange: false }): Promise<boolean>
```

In your case you can use `this.router.navigate('/pause');`

Assuming that you have router variable from Router service injected in constructor.

```
 constructor(private router: Router, private http: HttpClient) {}
```

For more info go to [this link](https://angular.io/api/router/Router)

Comment: The problem is that the routing module for angular will only direct me to components that are within my angular app. My `/pause` endpoint is from my server which means that the routing module will return an error saying that it cannot find a `pause` component

Comment: In this case you should use absolute url of that service and use router.navigateByUrl

Comment: I have tried using router.navigateByUrl before but it gave me an error `Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes.` which leads me to believe that it is still looking for a route within my angular client

Answer (score 0):

Although this might not be a direct solution to the question I was asking, I have solved the problem that I was facing. I figured that the only way I could call the endpoints was using the `subscribe()` observable so I continued to use it in my `music-control.compononent.ts`. Instead, I went to my server-side code and added `res.json(null)` to parse it to my angular client. By doing so, this enables me to convert non-JSON objects (which is the response I'm getting from Spotify) to JSON and send that which allows the subscribe to observe it nicely.

Here's my server-side code:

```
app.get('/pause', function(req, res) {
    client.get('access_token', (err, data) => {
        axios({
            method: 'PUT',
            url: `https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player/pause`,
            headers: { Authorization: "Bearer " + data }
        }).then(function (response) {
            console.log("song is paused!");
            res.json(null);
        }).catch((err) => console.log("uh-oh! song is unable to pause", err))
    })
})
```